# Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON, Spring MVC 4.2 and Hibernate JPA issue

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jackson

When Spring MVC try to convert a JPA object that has a bi-directional association into JSON by jackson 2.6.1 , I keep getting

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)
```

and first entity is:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer userId;
    @JsonManagedReference
    private UserClass userClass;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "userId", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
}

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "userClassId")

public UserClass getUserClass() {
    return this.userClass;
}
.......
}
```

the second is:

```
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.Table;
 ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_class")
public class UserClass implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer userClassId;
@JsonBackReference
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>(0);

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "userClassId", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getUserClassId() {
    return this.userClassId;
}


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userClass")
public List<User> getUsers() {
     return this.users;
}
```

and here is dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

I used "@JsonIgnore", "@JsonIdentityInfo" and "XmlTransient" for prevent recursion but both of them not working and the server report this error. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Edit:
And Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain:
sss.com.model.UserClass["users"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->sss.com.model.User["userClass"]->sss.com.model.UserClass["users"]->
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->sss.com.model.User["userClass"]->sss.com.model.UserClass["users"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->sss.com.model.User["userClass"]->sss.com.model.UserClass["users"]... .
 nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: 
sss.com.model.UserClass["users"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->sss.com.model.User["userClass"]->sss.com.model.UserClass["users"]->
org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->sss.com.model.User["userClass"]->sss.com.model.UserClass["users"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->sss.com.model.User["userClass"]->sss.com.model.UserClass["users"]... . with root cause
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.IOException.<init>(IOException.java:58)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException.<init>(JsonProcessingException.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException.<init>(JsonProcessingException.java:41)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.<init>(JsonMappingException.java:143)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:689)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:656)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:656)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:656)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675)
...
```

SOLVED:
In my original entity I have 5 bidirectional relation but, just, I was annotated one relation. The reason is tomcat didn't print exception in result page and i don't check tomcat log file.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Stack trace added. Thank you

Comment: A free piece of advice, don't use Your JPA entities for generating JSON, create a set of DTOs used between the frontent/services and the datamodel, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just put `@JsonIgnore`

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userClass")
public List<User> getUsers() {
     return this.users;
}
```

This will ignore lazy load object and fix your issue.

**Update**

- According to [Udara Seneviratne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5549301/udara-seneviratne) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41210447/1283715), You can handle `bi-directional relationship` by `@JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference`.

Comment: That worked for me too. But I don't understand why at some point for certain data objects a infinite recursion occurs.

Comment: @Brain Spring Hibernate Transaction session gone after @ Transactional block ends, when jackson try to lazy load users from proxy hibernate object exception thrown as session already ended.

Comment: thank you. That makes sense. Could it help then to use Hibernate.initialize(...) in order to prevent this error?

Comment: This will just ignore the particular field(List<User>) from the response. Following link has a solution for that http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Answer (score 7):

@JsonIgnore just ignore the annotated field from the result. If you need to include exception caused field also with the result, use @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference according to following tutorial. http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

If a class has more than one bi-directional relationships, better to use @JsonIdentityInfo

Answer (score 3):

It can be done by many ways

- Remove the getter method from one of the class.
- Use @JsonIgnore in One of the class
     (Problem : In Both above cases it will ignore the field from the result.)

  If You use below annotations, It will include the field also
- @JsonManagedReference, @JsonBackReference
- @JsonIdentityInfo(
  generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
  property = "id")

Answer (score 1):

Try to add  @XmlTransient annotation above manytoone reference side ,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
 ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {
private Integer userId;
@JsonManagedReference
private UserClass userClass;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "userId", unique = true, nullable = false)
 public Integer getUserId() {
  return this.userId;
 }

 @XmlTransient
 @ManyToOne()
 @JoinColumn(name = "userClassId")

  public UserClass getUserClass() {
  return this.userClass;
}
 .......
}
```

Comment: I add this annotation(@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient) but, again, i see that error. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Ok. As per my understanding this issue gives circular reference. So If you use XmlTransient annotation. this will ignore field from response. this annotation need to add all the entities where  manytoone annotation used. also try to remove json related annotations(JsonManagedReference,JsonIgnore,JsonIdentityInfo etc)