# Unable to return HQL getResultList as JSON

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest

Rest Controller
...

```
@GET
@Path("/employee")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String loginEmployee() {
    
    Transaction transaction=null;
    Session session=null;
    session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    transaction=session.beginTransaction();
    Employee e=new Employee();
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper(); 

    TypedQuery<Employee> query=session.createQuery("FROM Employee ", Employee.class);
    List<Employee> list=query.getResultList();
    
    transaction.commit();
    try {
        System.out.println(list);
        return mapper.writeValueAsString("Success");
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e1);
    }
    return "Failed";
}
```

...
Hibernate
...

```
public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
     if (sessionFactory == null) {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            
            Properties settings = new Properties();
            settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, 
    "org.postgresql.Driver");
            settings.put(Environment.URL, URL);
            settings.put(Environment.USER, USERNAME);
            settings.put(Environment.PASS, PASSWORD);
            settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, 
    "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
            settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
           
    settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, 
    "thread");
            settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
            configuration.setProperties(settings);
            
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(BaseTable.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Employee.class);
            
            
            
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
         }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

...
Employee
...

```
@Entity
public class Employee extends BaseTable implements EmployeeDAO {
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
/*  public Employee(String first_name, String last_name, String username, String 
     password, double salary, String email,
        String phonenum) { 
    super(first_name,last_name,username,password,salary,email,
    phonenum);
  }

public Employee(){}
*/

private List<SupportCase> cases=new ArrayList<>();
...

...
}
```

...
Base class
...

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseTable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name="firstname")
  private String firstName;

  @Column(name="lastname")
  private String lastName;

  @Column(name="username")
  private String username;

  @Column(name="password")
  private String password;

  @Column(name ="salary")
  private double salary;

  @Column(name="email")
  private String email;

  @Column(name="phonenum")
  private String phonenum;

  protected BaseTable(String first_name, String last_name, String username, String 
     password, double salary, String email,
        String phonenum) {
    
    this.firstName = first_name;
    this.lastName = last_name;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.salary = salary;
    this.email = email;
    this.phonenum = phonenum;
  }

  public BaseTable() {}

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getFirst_name() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public void setFirstName(String first_name) {
    this.firstName = first_name;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.lastName = last_name;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
  }

  public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public String getPhonenum() {
    return phonenum;
  }

  public void setPhonenum(String phonenum) {
    this.phonenum = phonenum;
  }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
        return "BaseTable {id=" + id + ", first_name=" + firstName + ", last_name=" + 
        lastName + ", username="
            + username + ", password=" + password + ", salary=" + salary + ", email=" + 
        email + ", phonenum="
            + phonenum + "}";
  }

}
```

...
Output
...

**Hibernate: select employee0_.id as id1_0_, employee0_.email as email2_0_, employee0_.firstname as firstnam3_0_, employee0_.lastname as lastname4_0_, employee0_.password as password5_0_, employee0_.phonenum as phonenum6_0_, employee0_.salary as salary7_0_, employee0_.username as username8_0_ from Employee employee0_
[BaseTable {id=122, first_name=Sri, last_name=Va, username=csfwea, password=afdcfc, salary=10000.0, email=abc@gmail.com, phonenum=123456789}, BaseTable {id=124, first_name=Sri, last_name=Va, username=csfwea, password=afdcfc, salary=10000.0, email=abc@gmail.com, phonenum=123456789}]
Hibernate: select cases0_.id as id6_2_0_, cases0_.sid as sid1_2_0_, cases0_.sid as sid1_2_1_, cases0_.date as date2_2_1_, cases0_.id as id6_2_1_, cases0_.method as method3_2_1_, cases0_.purpose as purpose4_2_1_, cases0_.status as status5_2_1_ from SupportCase cases0_ where cases0_.id=?**

The Error I'm getting :
**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException**

printStackTrace error is going about 1000 lines, so I just caught the exception.

However, the list is printing on the console but, when I try to **return** this **list (result list of the hibernate query) as JSON it throws JSONProcessingException**. I want to return the list as JSON data. I'm trying this for 2 days but I couldn't get the result. Please guide me how to return this as JSON. Thanks in advance.

I'm getting JSON response if I include the employee constructor which I've commented above, otherwise, it doesn't return but still I'm getting the desired output in the console. Why??

---

Problem solved: Include @JsonIgnore
[Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON, Spring MVC 4.2 and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354856/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-spring-mvc-4-2-and-hibernate-jpa-issue)

Comment: Attach Error logs ?

Comment: You can see that error in output. printStackTrace error goes about 1000 lines.

Comment: Problem solved. All I need to do is include @JsonIgnore above the Mapping. Here is the referral link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354856/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-spring-mvc-4-2-and-hibernate-jpa-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generated hibernate column names are in snake_case where you've mapped them in your entity class differently.

Change the column names in `@Column` in your entity class as snake_case and it should solve the problem

---

Problem solved by including @JsonIgnore

Comment: It was initially in the snake case and I changed into camel case to check whether it works or not. It doesn't work in both the cases. I'm able to get the result in console but not as json. However, I also tried now, it comes up with the same error.

Comment: can you please provide details about `SupportCase` here?

Comment: I didn't implement that code. As of now I've just related with that class. The problem is that I'm not able to return the Employee records as JSON response, if I didn't include the constructor. But still I'm getting the output on the console.